# Solving the multiple integral $\int \int_D \sqrt{x^2+y^2+3}dx dy$, D:{$1\le x^2+y^2\le 4, y\le \sqrt3x, y\ge \frac x{\sqrt 3}$}

Tags: calculus, integration

$\iint_D \sqrt{x^2+y^2+3}\, dx dy$, $D=\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 1 \leq x^2+y^2\le 4, y\le \sqrt3x, y\ge \frac x{\sqrt 3} \right\}$.

So I've started by drawing two circles, One with $R_1 =1$, Other with $R_2=2$

Then i drawed the lines $y_1=\sqrt3x$ and $y_2 = \frac x{\sqrt 3}$.

Using the polar system i'll need to calculate:

$\int^{\pi/3}_{\pi/6}dθ\int_1^2\sqrt{r^2+3}*r*dr$

Using substiution on: $\int_1^2\sqrt{r^2+3}*r*dr$ i get: $\frac {7^{3/2}}{3}-\frac {4^{3/2}}{3}$.

Then i need to multiply by $\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{\pi}{6}$

And the final answer is: $\frac {7^{3/2}-4^{3/2}}{18}\pi$.

The answer should be: $\frac {5(7\sqrt 7 -8)}{18}$, I'm pretty close but it seems like i'm missing something, I tried solving this one a couple of times and still got to the same answer.

I need help, What am i missing?

Comment: Are you sure about the finial given answer?

Comment: The answer you say cannot be as there is no $\;\pi \;$ in it. I think Babak was pointing in this direction...

Comment: Its written in a paper with questions and solutions.

Comment: And just for the record, I don't mind that their answer is wrong. I want to know why mine is.

Comment: Your five ($\,5\,$) in the answer must be  $\,\pi\,$ and then all's peachy...

Comment: Haha, You are right. :-) This one drove me nuts for an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've done *almost* everything right, but $\;1\le r\le\frac6{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{3\sqrt2}{\sqrt 5}\;$ ! , so

$$\int\limits_1^2r\sqrt{r^2+3}\,dr=\left.\frac12\frac23(r^2+3)^{3/2}\right|_1^2=\frac13\left(7^{3/2}-8\right)$$

and together with

$$\int\limits_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3}d\theta=\frac{\pi}6\;,\;\;\text{we get:}$$

$$\frac{\pi}{18}(7\sqrt 7-8)$$

I can't understand where does that five you wrote there come from...

Comment: I've edited the original post, I didn't write the second integral part. Seems like you and i got the same answers. Thanks.

Comment: Yes...it is confusing and slightly annoying they (the final answer) write $\,4^{3/2}\,$ instead of simply $\,8\,$ . For things like these I'd take 1-2 points from my students.

Comment: @DonAntonio: just to be Devil's advocate, one might leave the answer in that form for pedagogical reasons.